# Connecting 2 external monitors causes my laptop to become unusable

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

I have Dell Latitude E6500 with Nvidia Quadro 160M and I just bought two DELL U2410 external monitors . I connected one to the DisplayPort and the other to VGA. After a while of using Skype, Outlook, and Firefox Windows 7 x64 slows to crawl. I've been trying everything I can think of, even connecting only one of the monitors (They have a 1920x1200 native resolution) but to no avail. Finally, I disconnected both and after 15 reboots everything is running smoothly again.

Before I got the new Dell monitors I was using an old 19" Samsung 1600x1050 through VGA without a problem. I've never heard of monitors doing this to a system before (I've been trying to pinpoint the issue for some hours now).

Anybody had something similar? I've newest nvidia drivers, fully updated windows 7 with Intel SSD drive. I was even running quick tests/smart tests on the drive but it was passing without problems.

EDIT:

CPU is P9700 @ 2.8Ghz and 4GB of RAM with Intel SSD and Nvidia Quadro 160M. The laptop runs natively with 1920x1080p on my main laptop monitor.

After the issue I reported above: I've disconnected VGA monitor and only 1 monitor was connected with Laptop's lid closed. After a reboot the laptop ran at a crawl straight from POST. A hard shut down with button held for 5 secs was the only thing that restored normal operation... For now...

Comment: It could be that your computer is not graphically powerful enough to power one (let alone two) 1920x1200 monitors, although this seems unlikely considering that your laptop is relatively new.

Comment: My new laptop is coming in few days so it's just temporary situation. It's just weird that it allows me to use both monitors without problem now. For 10 minutes already..

Comment: CPU is P9700 @ 2.8Ghz and 4GB of RAM with Intel SSD and Nvidia Quadro 160M.

Comment: See my edit. My laptop is also capable of running 1920x1200 natively. And the issue is occuring just now.. even with 1 monitor connected to DP... and laptop's lid closed. Grr...

Comment: Is there anything in the windows event log? What is the CPU usage like while it's acting slow?

Comment: It's 100% cpu usage. But whatever application I kill that is topping next one goes up. I was killing outlook, skype, explorer, svhosts.. basically every single app. I can't fix this while the problem happens. I have to reboot (but shutdown not just reboot otherwise the problem starts up from beginning straight after boot).

Comment: I've updated main post with some logs.

Comment: I've called Dell and their sending technician tommorow with new motherboard. Will let you guys know if the problem comes out again. Unless I get new computer sooner then I won't have "need" for more testing :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had Dell replace the motherboard and so far so good. Been working without problems for few long hours. Funny thing is this wasn't noticable in normal day to day work. Without monitors everything was fine and dandy.